# Bootstrap table responsive grey line

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, html-table

I have grey line under my responsive table. I don't know from where it comes. How it gets created. Here a pic:

[image]

My html code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div ng-app="appGenerator" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="table in tablenames">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="ttable in table.table" ng-click="setSelect(ttable)">
                        <td>{{ttable}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

My js code:

```
var app = angular.module('appGenerator', ['ngRoute']).controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get('GeneratedFiles/RelationsBC.bbTable').success(function (tableResponse) {
    $scope.tablenames = tableResponse.table;
});
$scope.setSelect = function (ttable) {
    alert(ttable);
}
});
```

Comment: I think the CSS code would be more useful here

Comment: There is no CSS in use for this.